# How do I add node values from one xml document into another xml document?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have been stuck on this one for days. I hope to get help from you great people.

What I am trying to do in VB.NET is use a variable named strCourtNCIC to hold a value. Then I want to use the strCourtNCIC value to look inside object objXmlSimpleTypeDoc and find an EnumerationValue node that have @code value that matches the value in strCourtNCIC variable.

In this question strCourtNCIC = MN010015J. This can be a different value but I already got the value from some other document.

After I find the correct EnumerationValue node, I want to get the values for children and add them to my objXmlResponseDoc. The result should look like the one I posted here.

The objXmlResponseDoc should look like this

```
<GetCaseInformationResponseMessage>
    <CourtLocation>
        <CourtName>Emily</CourtName>
        <ORINumber>MN010015J</ORINumber>
        <MNCISNodeID>111</MNCISNodeID>
        <PhoneNumber>724-820-7123</PhoneNumber>
    </CourtLocation>
</GetCaseInformationResponseMessage>
```

Here is the objXmlSimpleTypeDoc that need to get the EnumerationValue with @code that matches strCourtNCIC value (MN010015J). Then get value for CountyName, ORINumber, MNCISNodeID and PhoneNumber then add them to my new object named objXmlResponseDoc.

```
<SimpleTypeCompanion enumerates="CourtLocationTextType">
    <EnumerationValue code="MN010015J">
        <Text>Emily County</Text>
        <AssociatedValue type="MNCISNodeID">
            <Text>111</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="CountyName">
            <Text>Emily</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="PhoneNumber">
            <Text>724-820-7123</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
    </EnumerationValue>
    <EnumerationValue code="DC19DAKDC">
        <Text>Pope County</Text>
        <AssociatedValue type="MNCISNodeID">
            <Text>112</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="CountyName">
            <Text>Pope</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
    </EnumerationValue>
</SimpleTypeCompanion>
```

Here is the VB.NET code that I need help with to add the node values from correct EnumerationValue node.

```
'Produce the response message
objXmlResponseDoc = New XmlDocument
objXmlResponseDoc.AppendChild(objXmlResponseDoc.CreateElement("GetCaseInformationResponseMessage"))
objXmlMNCISData = Library.v4.Case.GetIxmlForCaseNumber(strCaseNumber, "CourtCaseHeaderGroup", False)
'CourtNCIC = MN010015J
strCourtNCIC = objXmlMNCISData.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Case/Court/CourtNCIC").InnerText
'New CourtNCIC as xml element
objXmlCourtNCICElement = objXmlMNCISData.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Case/Court/CourtNCIC")
'Access the CourtLocationTextType simple type. 
objXmlSimpleTypeDoc = Msc.Integration.CourtXml.Library.v4.SimpleType.GetCompanionFile("CourtLocationTextType")
'Court location
objXmlCourtLocationNode = objXmlResponseDoc.CreateElement("CourtLocation")
objXmlResponseDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(objXmlCourtLocationNode)
'CourtName
objXmlCourtNameElement = objXmlResponseDoc.CreateElement("CourtName")
strCourtName = objXmlCourtLocationNode.SelectSingleNode("EnumerationValue[@code=" + strCourtNCIC + "]/Test").InnerText
objXmlCourtLocationNode.AppendChild(objXmlCourtNameElement)
'ORINumber
objXmlORINumberElement = objXmlResponseDoc.CreateElement("ORINumber")
objXmlCourtLocationNode.AppendChild(objXmlORINumberElement)
'MNCISNode ID
objXmlMNCISNodeIDElement = objXmlResponseDoc.CreateElement("MNCISNodeID")
objXmlCourtLocationNode.AppendChild(objXmlMNCISNodeIDElement)
'PhoneNumber 
objXmlPhoneNumberElement = objXmlResponseDoc.CreateElement("PhoneNumber")
objXmlCourtLocationNode.AppendChild(objXmlPhoneNumberElement)
```

Comment: What does the final xml file look like after the two files are combined?

Comment: The new xml with values should look like this. It is the same one I posted here without values.  <GetCaseInformationResponseMessage>
 <CourtLocation>
  <CourtName>Emily</CourtName>
  <ORINumber>MN010015J</ORINumber>
  <MNCISNodeID>111</MNCISNodeID>
  <PhoneNumber>724-820-7123</PhoneNumber>
 </CourtLocation>
</GetCaseInformationResponseMessage>

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq (The latest msdn xml library for Net) is very easy :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"

    Sub Main()
        Dim inputDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim xmlHeader As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><GetCaseInformationResponseMessage></GetCaseInformationResponseMessage>"
        Dim outputDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlHeader)
        Dim response As XElement = outputDoc.Root

        Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, XElement) = inputDoc.Descendants("EnumerationValue") _
            .GroupBy(Function(x) CType(x.Attribute("code"), String), Function(y) y) _
            .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.FirstOrDefault())

        Dim code As String = "MN010015J"
        Dim enumerationValue As XElement = dict(code)

        AddNode(enumerationValue, response)

    End Sub

    Public Sub AddNode(enumerationValue As XElement, response As XElement)
        Dim courtLocation As New XElement("CourtLocation")
        response.Add(courtLocation)
        Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = enumerationValue.Elements("AssociatedValue") _
            .GroupBy(Function(x) CType(x.Attribute("type"), String), Function(y) CType(y.Element("Text"), String)) _
            .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.FirstOrDefault())

        courtLocation.Add(New XElement("CourtName", CType(enumerationValue.Element("Text"), String)))
        courtLocation.Add(New XElement("ORINumber", CType(enumerationValue.Attribute("code"), String)))
        If dict.ContainsKey("MNCISNodeID") Then
            courtLocation.Add(New XElement("MNCISNodeID", dict("MNCISNodeID")))
        End If
        If dict.ContainsKey("PhoneNumber") Then
            courtLocation.Add(New XElement("PhoneNumber", dict("PhoneNumber")))
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Hi jdweng. the xml document I am copying from has many EnumerationValue nodes. This is why I need to find the correct node before copying the values of the  children of that parent node. For example the node I want this time is the one with @code =MN010015J. I need to have a variable to hold MN010015J value and use it to find the correct node in the object objXmlSimpleTypeDoc